# Run a program while another program is active (Autohotkey)

Tags: autohotkey

I was wondering if i could get AHK-script to automatically launch a program in the background when i start another.

Example:

Execute `C:\any.exe`. 
AHK launches: `C:\monitor.exe`

When `any.exe` is closed, ahk should kill `monitor.exe`

Awsome if you guys could help me.

Edit: Note that i am a complete newcomer to programming or scripting in every way you can think of

Comment: No, you cannot get the script. SO is a Q&A site, not a free freelance site. If you a new to autohotkey, read the documentation and examples, then ask if you have a specific problem with the code.

Comment: The question was "IF" and not "give me the code".
All i wanted to know was if ahk was technically able to handle this in a viable way. I have got the program in c, but i do not want to run a seperate exe on the system while ahk is running anyways.

Comment: Yeah you can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out `timer` in the autohotkey docs.

You could set a timer that checks every 5 seconds to run `winexist` to test for the existence of c:\any.exe - and when it returns `true` then your code could run c:\monitor.exe

Now that your code knows that c:\any.exe is running, your code could launch a second timer that checks for when its process is closed (check out `process` in the ahk docs).  When it is closed, then use `winkill` to close the c:\monitor.exe process.

So, look up these commands:

- `winexist`
- `timer`
- `process`

Comment: worked for me. However i used a different script for the startup so that the monitor.exe starts before any.exe (together with the script which then checks if monitor.exe is active, while any.exe is) - it then shuts itself down. Thanks for your input!

Comment: If it were me, I'd make the script check for c:\any.exe as soon as it starts and then check also on a timer after that.  That way the script will begin working immediately.  You can always keep the scripts separate and then use `#include myscript.ahk` to load the monitoring script.